# QGraphicsWebView incorrectly expands horizontally with unused white bars (window.outerWidth >> window.innerWidth)

Tags: qt, jquery-mobile, qt4, qtwebkit

I'm using a view hierarchy of

**QMainWindow** > **central widget** > **QVBoxLayout** > **QGraphicsView (800x600 fixed)** > **class deriving from QGraphicsScene** > **QGraphicsWebView** (800x600)

When I load a jQuery Mobile powered HTML file and use the horizontal slide transition between pages, the value of `window.outerWidth` grows to 2400 pixels. But the actual page width, and value of `window.innerWidth`, remains at 800. The web view then shows 800 pixel-wide white bars at the left and right (horizontal scrollbar also expands to 2400px), with the new jQM "page" in the middle. Right-clicking in the white bars does *not* show the QtWebView context menu, but right-clicking in the middle works. I enabled developer tools [1] which told me that the HTML, BODY and DATA-ROLE="page" elements have the correct width of 800px.

This is working in browsers like Firefox and Chrome, so I think it's a bug in Qt's web view implementation or a setting that I have missed. The problem seems to come from the fact that the jQM pages which are sliding in/out during transitions are considered for the width. Why does `window.outerWidth` get such a wrong value? Note that any size policies on the web view do not have an effect. Any ideas what else I could try?

---

[1] "Inspect" context menu option:

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(
    QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled,
    true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by upgrading to Qt 5 which has the latest WebKit. It however creates new trouble, so first try if the rest of your web pages work before switching to the newly released 5.0.0.